# Automating the logging of each response time running through postman via newman in AzureDevOps Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, postman, performance-testing, ado, postman-collection-runner

I am a fairly new engineer (about 1 year) and I was tasked with figuring out a solution to shift performance testing as far left as possible.. to fit into a DevOps model. What I am trying to achieve is: 
 - Add additional scripting into the existing Newman to record the response time of EACH request in the collection.
- Generate a report each time the pipeline (testing for pass or fail of API scripts) is invoked to run, and save it in ADO along with the pass/fail results.

I do NOT want to have to create a collection for each individual API, but rather have large collections run daily (ex; Web services API's, app API's, UI API's)

ANY direction or help would be super helpful, I've googled a lot but just can't come up with a lightweight solution that isn't going to negatively impact the overall testing or dev process.

Comment: Are you using any reporters with Newman?

Comment: It is generating a report, yes.

Comment: Hi, how the things going now? Could you achieve running postman via newman in azure devops pipeline now? If yes, you can [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) thus other SO users will be able to see whether the solution works. If you are still facing some issues please leave a comment so we can still help you .

Answer (score 0):

In azure devops pipeline, you can use **Newman the cli Companion for Postman** to analyze the response time by install extension [Newman the cli Companion for Postman](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=carlowahlstedt.NewmanPostman) first:

[image]

In the configuration of task:

- Add your **collection url** which get from Postman into the
  **Collection Source Type**:

[image]

[image]

- Then fill your **local Newman path** and the **html report export
  path** in the task.

[image]

**Note:** Don't forget install Newman locally first.

- After you run the pipeline, the task will run Newman and export the
  report with `.html` to the path you specified. As the below pic
  shown(this is my report), you can see the response time and the
  results of all APIs in the collection.

[image]

Since you want the report saved in ADO repos, I' afraid you need to use git command to push local `.html` report to Azure Devops.